# realtime graph null pointer exception ar invoke virtual method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am making a real time graph but keep having an mistake with the line:

```
series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastXPoint, rnd.nextInt(10)),true, 100);
```

the error that keeps coming is called

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries.appendData(com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPointInterface, boolean, int)' on a null object reference
```

How do I solve it??

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: It appears that your series object is null